# Primefaces p:datatable - Change {CurrentPageReport}

Tags: javascript, jsf, dynamic, datatable, primefaces

I`m searching and searching but I can not find anything to solve my problem.
I use a DataTable (Primefaces) and wondered how I can change the language/output of some fields.

More precisely, I want to change the {CurrentPageReport} in PaginatorTemplate.
Now, it looks very simple: (0 of 100).
I want to have it like this (Page 0 of 100, 500 results).

I tried a lot, but nothing works.
The last I did was:

```
function change_text () {
    $(".ui-paginator-current").each (function() {
        $(this).html("Simple test");
    });     
}

$(".ui-icon").each(
            function(index) {
                $( this ).bind ("click",function(){ change_text (); });
            }
    );
```

(ui-icon is part of each button in the table.)

But this is not really effective as you can see :-)
This solution works half-way. When I press on a button (next page, previous page) the text in .ui-paginator-current field changes back to the default template.
I know.. the reason is because this field is also being reloaded.

I also tried to change Primefaces Code but I can`t find the correct code area.

I am working with JSF 2.0.3 and PrimeFaces 2.2.1.
How can I solve my problem? Can I load paginatorTemplate from a bean?
It would really help me if I could change the text from "0 of 100" to "0 aus 100" (german).

Hope you guys can help me, like every time I have a problem.

Ioannis K.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Found it:

```
<p:dataTable currentPageReportTemplate="{currentPage} #{loc.of} {totalPages}" />
```

for those who are interested in it :-)

*Now: I have it like this:

```
paginatorTemplate="{FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {CurrentPageReport} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink}"

currentPageReportTemplate="(Entries: {startRecord} - {endRecord} of {totalRecords}, Page: {currentPage}/{totalPages})"
```

Hope this helps you guys!

Comment: You can also do this as well: `currentPageReportTemplate="#{msg.PAGE_LABEL}"` where `#{msg.PAGE_LABEL}` is `PAGE_LABEL={currentPage} of {totalPages}` that is stored in an English resource bundle (MessageResources_en.properties). For other languages, just translate the word '**of**' and store each translation in its separate resource bundle, for example, do this for a French resource bundle (MessageResources_fr.properties): `PAGE_LABEL={currentPage} sur {totalPages}`. Hope this helps anyone else coming across this post in the future.

Comment: @Ioannis: That actually helps a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but PrimeFaces does support German locale. Have you tried setting the locale in your bean to see if "0 of 100" changes to "0 aus 100" ?

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale(new Locale("de"));
```

Comment: Yes I think I did. My (Our) project supports multilanguage and it checks on its own which default language in the browser of the user is set via faces-config.xhtml. FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().setLocale() is being executed automatically and it works. When I change my browser language to german, my whole site is on german but not the page report.

Comment: Ioannis K.: You might want to add that as an answer and accept that instead so the solution is easier to find for others.

Comment: You`re right Jörn. I did it now.I`ve just to learn  how the things work here.